# Customizing item_default.html display template to use another Control Display template

Tags: 2013, search-results, display-template

I have created a copy of Control_SearchSearch.html cotrol display template and now I want to make Item_default.html display template use this Control Display template. how do I make it to use my control display template?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new result type based on the ootb Default Result Type. There you can specify your new template as the default template. Depending on the result types, you might have to override some more result types as well (check whether they reference the default item template).